# WordPress Custom Post Title Key?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom post type called Slides on my WordPress. Each post will be turned into a slide in a slideshow on its parent post.

Anyway, I am using the custom fields plugin Types to create the custom fields. The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to display each post's title. All the actual custom fields are displaying fine but I can't seem to figure out how to display the custom post's title (which is odd because it's technically not even a custom field).

Here's the php code I used to populate the slide's variables:

```
<?php foreach ($slides as $slide) { ?>
    <?php if (get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'wpcf-image', true)) {
    $thetitle = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'title', true);
    $image = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'wpcf-image', true);
    $caption = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'wpcf-caption', true);
    $credit = get_post_meta($slide->ID, 'wpcf-credit', true);
    ?>
```

$thetitle is the only one experiencing issues.

If anyone could help me figure out what's wrong with the thetitle code, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: It's been a while since I've used WordPress, but is the title not something like wp_title?

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLandrum . I tried using that as the key, but it didn't work.

Comment: OK, I think I know what's going on. You have a couple options: you can add a title as a custom field called ``title'' or you can point to the post's title via something like `the_title()`. That is, if I understand correctly what you are doing.

Comment: I believe the second option would be easier to implement and easier on your work flow. `$thetitle = the_title();` should just work.

Comment: The issue with using 'the_title();' is it displays the parent post's title.

Comment: Have you tried starting a new loop for your slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of a post (regardless of the post_type) is not meta. The title and content are part of the post (stored directly in wp_posts).

You can do this:

```
$thetitle = get_the_title($slide->ID);
```

You can see the official documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, this also displays the parent post's title rather than the slides' titles even thought the slide ID is being used.

Comment: What do you mean "this **also** displays"?

Comment: Oh, sorry, someone else suggested I use the_title();, which also displayed the parents' title. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I didn't, sadly. Everything I try displays the parent post title not the title of the child post I want... it's strange. You can see it here (and this is using get_the_title): http://renegademagsu.com/

Comment: @Noelle have you tried starting a new loop around your slides? Look at this example: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops

Comment: @pmandell Turns out I forgot to echo the new variable in the HTML so this is why it wasn't working!